# UIPageViewController with a last view without page indicator

Tags: ios, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to have 4 views that the user can swipe left or right.
For this I am planning to use UIPageViewController.

What is special is that the last view should not have the page indicator at all. I would like to swipe it away with the view that is before the last one. Is this possible with UIPageViewController?

Here is a picture of a swipe moving to the last view:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a) four dots on every page, or b) five dots on the first four pages and no dots on the final page?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect screenshot - I want b) - the final page should not be counted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's impossible to achieve what you say with `UIPageViewController`. Because you can't get the value how far the current view is moved by now.

To get that value you can custom a `UIScrollView` and animate the page indicator yourself in the delegate method `- scrollViewDidScroll:`

Comment: Any ideas what can I use? I am already using a custom interactive transition for this, but I find that the scroll view (UIPageViewController) swipe is much smother

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for conditionally showing the page control, depending on what page you're on.

- If you could get the `UIPageViewController` to query its  `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`, you could try returning 0 from `presentationCountForPageViewController:` while transitioning to the last view controller, but it will never be a good solution, as you're trying to circumvent what the controller is internally managing for you.
- You can use `UIAppearance` to change the color of `UIPageControl`.

  This can be used to only apply a style for a particular view controller, as follows:

  ```
  UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[LastViewController class], nil];
  pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  ```

  This, however, won't remove it from the view, and the page control's gestures would still be active.